# Eclipse and Team Explorer Everywhere Problem

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer

I have some problems with Eclipse and Team Explorer Everywhere.

I installed and added a server to Eclipse. But now i couldn't add new servers. Because, server button is disabled.

[image]

I wonder, how can i add new servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you have a project in your workspace already shared with Team Foundation Server using the plug-in?

You can only have one TFS workspace (and therefore one server connection) in an Eclipse workspace at a time.  If you want to connect to another TFS server then better to switch to a new Eclipse workspace.  Alternatively you can close all the projects in your Eclipse workspace that are connected to TFS or delete them from your workspace.

Comment: I will try at home and inform you about results. Thanks for you answer. By the way, i am reading your ALM book, it is wonderfull. congratulations :)

Comment: You are right, when i changed my workspace, servers button became enable.